# Android sqlite `db.execSQL()` is force close

Tags: android, sqlite

This is fragment from db class existing on my `onCreate` method. Above this method was defined a constructor with proper arguments.

So, when running it, the **runtime log** for this method shows that it executed up to **run1.2** but not further.

---

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try{
          db = getWritableDatabase();
          db.beginTransaction();
          android.util.Log.w("check", "run1.1");
          String query = " CREATE TABLE check ( id INTEGER )";
          android.util.Log.w("check", "run1.2");
          db.execSQL(query, null);
          android.util.Log.w("check", "run1.3");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            android.util.Log.w("check", e.toString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: anybody who can check above problem!!!

Comment: can you please post your error log

Comment: @Zubair_2024 this question is a lit bit confuse. I changed it a lit bit. What mean "not further statement" ? You could need more precise providing logging information as well as which statements is not running.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the second parameter of your `execSQL` call. This is the execSQL code from SQLiteDatabase.java:

```
public void execSQL(String sql, Object[] bindArgs) throws SQLException {
    if (bindArgs == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty bindArgs");
    }
    executeSql(sql, bindArgs);
}
```

Use only:

```
db.execSQL(query);
```